# Adding vertical space between lines in vim

Tags: layout, vim

**Summary:** I'd like to view my text in vim with a small bit of extra vertical space between **some** lines.

I'm writing latex in vim, and have each sentence on a new line. I'd like to add a little bit of vertical space (a few pixels) between sentences to make them clearer. I don't want to add anything to the buffer, just to how I view it.

I don't want to add a whole newline, as that has meaning in latex.

Example text:

```
Conventional wisdom states that a compiled program should run an
order-of-magnitude faster than an interpreted program.
In our experience, however, dynamic scripting languages do not follow this rule
of thumb.
Instead, a program written in a scripting language spends most of its run-time
handling dynamic features, such as dynamic types and \code{zval}s.
This limits the potential improvement of simply removing the interpreter loop.
This is particularly important for a compiler like \phc{} which re-uses the PHP
system, as many of the code paths executed will be the same, whether the program
is interpreted or compiled.
```

Any ideas?

**Update:**

Maybe something with breakat, linebreak, showbreak and linespace, but I dont think this is enough.

- linespace will put space between every line, but I'd like space only after lines ending in `.`
- The others aren't enough without some equivalent to linespace

Comment: Why is it not enough? Please explain what you are missing, as `linespace` looked like what you were looking for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using gvim, can't you do this command?

```
:set linespace=5
```

Comment: Yeah. Looks good. It would be great to localize it only the lines with a `.` in them.

Comment: @Paul, Sorry mate, I think that that setting is locked in the global space.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using gvim, only vim, you can't change the line space or see any change when specifying "linespace=5" into vimrc. My solution was to change the line space in my terminal emulator, in my case Alacritty, using in my alacritty.yml:

```
font:
    offset:
        x: 0
        y: 5
```

You can try to make the same in your terminal emulator, BUT this will change the line space in all the terminal.